# Summing a Hash - how can I add find the total cost for the orders in this hash

Tags: ruby, hash, sum

```
basket = { 
"potato wedges" : 4.45 => 2,
"tiramisu : 4.95 => 2,
"diet coke" : 1.75 => 2
}
```

I want to sum this hash - the values represent the number of items, the number in the key represents the price.
hoW COULD i calculate the total price of these items\thANK YOU

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Ruby code, or is it? Can you update your question with the proper code for the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant to write a hash like this:

```
basket = { 
"potato wedges:4.45" => 2,
"tiramisu:4.95" => 2,
"diet coke:1.75" => 2
}
```

You could get the sum like this:

```
basket.sum {|k,v| k.split(':')[1].to_f * v}
#-> 22.3
```

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to create a an app that takes orders. I have a hash with a list of dishes and prices, and I have another method where I add the dishes and quantities e.g. potato wedges X 2 , diet coke x 3, and I need to find a way to get the total cost of these orders.

Comment: Edit the question to specify the problem. Try to explain in detail what you need, add examples and desired outputs for those examples.

Comment: @fairyduststars A good start would be to make your code in the question valid (when you run it it shouldn't throw an error)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use vector methods.

```
h = { 
  "potato wedges:4.45" => 2,
  "tiramisu:4.95" => 2,
  "diet coke:1.75" => 2
}
```

```
require 'matrix'

Vector[*h.keys.map { |s| s[/(?<=:).+/].to_f }].inner_product(Vector[*h.values])
  #=> 22.3
```

See [Vector::[]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-c-5B-5D), [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [Vector#inner_product](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-inner_product). The regular expression `/(?<=:).+/` reads, "match one or more characters (`.+`) immediately preceded by a colon", `(?<=:)` being a *postive lookbehind*.